# Javascript splice is removing everything but the element requested

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a pretty simple script that takes content from an input box, makes an array out of it, removes a desired element, and spits back the text.

I'm trying to use "splice()" to remove the item but it removes everything BUT that one item:

```
var listOfTitles = $('.title-list').val();
var arrayOfTitles = listOfTitles.split(',');
var updatedTitles = arrayOfTitles.splice(2,1);
$('.title-list').val(updatedTitles.join());
```

for example if I have this:

test1,test2,test3,test4

I can turn it into an array. I want to removed "test3" and output "test1,test2,test4". The problem is, it's returning "test3" not removing it.

jsfiddle of what's happening: http://jsfiddle.net/C95kN/

Comment: Where do you use splice in that code?

Comment: it was a typo, I edited the question and added a jsfiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Splice()` modifies the array in place and returns an array with the elements you remove.

What you want is `arrayOfTitles` not `updatedTitles`

See working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C95kN/1/

Comment: AH! I thought it gave the modified array as an output instead of directly modifying the array. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) changes the passed array and returns the removed elements. Simply do

```
arrayOfTitles.splice(2,1);
$('.title-list').val(arrayOfTitles.join());
```

Note that I supposed the `slice` instead of `splice` was a typo.

Comment: yes, it was a typo. I'll fix it. Here's a jsfiddle fo what I'm seeing: http://jsfiddle.net/C95kN/